# regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

What is this regex supposed to do, because it keeps giving back null?

```
var klass = this.rel.match(/facebox\[?\.(\w+)\]?/)
```

I thought it was extracting extra words from the rel attribute?

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matches

```
facebox   // facebox
\[?       // [ or nothing
\.        // .
(\w+)     // word*
\]?       // ] or nothing
```

Valid inputs:

```
facebox[.bb
facebox.bb]
facebox[.bb]
facebox.bb
```

Invalid inputs

```
facebox[bb]
faceboX[.bb]
Facebox.bb]
```

---

About `\w` *

> Matches any word character. Equivalent to the Unicode character categories [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]. If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified with the ECMAScript option, \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z_0-9].

**Reference**

- [RegExLib.com Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx)
- [Regular Expressions Reference - Basic Syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: How would you explain your evauation of the situation to somebody new to Regex: or in layman's terms?  I think such an addition to your orgininal answer would make it invaluable to future visitors, and garner more upvotes.

Comment: that is a perfect response except I think you meant to say that (\w+) matches a single word, and not "words"(unless they are separated by underscores) I believe it is the equivalent of ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).

Comment: @gnomed: Thanks :). I've updated my answer extending the explanation for `\w`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: That paragraph you quoted is talking about the .NET regex flavor.  The OP is using JavaScript, so ECMAScript mode is the *only* mode.

Comment: Now the regex is working. The browsers cache needed to be empty'd.